# identity.launchWebAuthFlow vs windows.create in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm new to chrome extensions but I can't seem to understand what value the `identity.launchWebAuthFlow` adds over `windows.create`. I'm trying to use Oauth from an external provider. There doesn't appear to be any automatic persistence of an identity token as part of that flow. Also other browsers do not (yet?) support the `identity.launchWebAuthFlow` function. Both of which point to NOT using it vs a normal popup.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Firefox and Opera, but not Edge: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/identity/launchWebAuthFlow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow) launches your authentication page in a window until it comes back to `https://<app-id>.chromiumapp.org/*`, and then the callback fires.

[`chrome.windows.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create) launches any URL and then fires the callback with the window object.

There's one significant advantage to `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`, from the docs:

> Since some auth flows may immediately redirect to a result URL, `launchWebAuthFlow` hides its web view until the first navigation either redirects to the final URL, or finishes loading a page meant to be displayed.

This means that you can seamlessly sign in (if your auth supports it)

Comment: That's helpful.  Seems like a small value to merit a different implementation but undoubtedly folks on the chrome team feel otherwise.